# Halt giraph when all vertex have converged

Tags: giraph

I'm new at Giraph, so maybe my question has an obvious response.

I'm implementing an algorithm on Giraph that needs to stop when all vertex have converged and do some computations afterwards.

My approach was halting every vertex once it has converged and keep working with the rest, once all of them are halted do the final computation. But I don't see a way to do it that way.

As my first idea does not seem to be correct I'm thinking in using an aggregator having a flag storing the status of the vertex, not halt any of the vertex during the process, and once the flag is active do the final computations and halt the vertex.

Which of these is the best practice or the only way to do it? Or should I do it in some other way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally used an aggregator to solve it:

https://github.com/joseprupi/okapi/tree/master/src/main/java/ml/grafos/okapi/clustering/ap